Get the Max value from a dataframe
I have a polars dataframe that contains the following columns ID, Values_A , Values_B. I'm trying to get the last date for a filter that im going to use later, so i need the get the most recent date of all my dataframe.
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    "ID" : [1,2,3],
    "Values_A" : [datetime(1,1,2),datetime(1,1,3),datetime(1,1,4)],
    "Values_B" : [datetime(1,1,4),datetime(1,1,7),datetime(1,1,2)]
}

dummy_df = pl.DataFrame(data)

dummy_df

Im using dummy_df.max() and my output is:
┌─────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ ID  ┆ Values_A            ┆ Values_B            │
│ --- ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ i64 ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 3   ┆ 0001-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 0001-01-07 00:00:00 │
└─────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘

However, i would to save it on a variable the maxium date, on this case 0001-01-07 00:00:00

You can use max_horizontal to get the maximum value across the row.

You should show the filter you want to perform because it's likely it can all be done using "expressions" instead of materializing values into Python variables.

if you want to just get max of all datetime columns into variable, you can do this:

selectors to select only datetime columns.
max_horizontal() to get max value of the row.
to_series() to convert DataFrame into Series.
max() to get max value of resulting series.

import polars.selectors as cs

dummy_df.select(pl.max_horizontal(cs.datetime())).to_series().max()

